# What does until November mean

Tags: meaning

I was told the job I worked at had til November. Is that the beginning of November or the end of November?

Comment: They had til November to pay me

Comment: Ask this question to your employer, or look in your contract, if there's one.

Comment: Can you quote the entire piece?  It is ambiguous, it could mean up to the 31st October or the first day of November or even the first week of November. I would not think it included the end of November.

Comment: Employment law - and employment practice - differ widely. Just from those details it is impossible to say what the conditions are. And even then, some employers will deliberately create a false impression. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

It is inherently ambiguous. There may be a standard interpretation in your context, but English grammar and lexicon cannot answer your question.